# Partially wrong encoding/decyphering (AES) in a c#+js stack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, encoding, aes

I'm decyphering an AES CBC encrypted string (json) in a controller, however the decrypted string is partially wrong: why / how ?

First I'm encrypting a padded json in javascript (using [aes-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js)):

```
AddPaddingText(text, size) {
    text += " ".repeat(size - text.length % size);
    return text;
}
Encrypt(decyphered, size) {
    var padded = this.AddPaddingText(decyphered, size);
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(padded);
    var encryptedBytes = this.aesCyCtr.encrypt(textBytes);
    return aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
}
var json = JSON.stringify([this.emailFieldValue, this.textFieldValue]);
this.cyphjson = this.Encrypt(json, 128);
```

`this.cyphjson` is sent to the api, and then:

```
    [Route("/contact/decrypt")]
    public IActionResult DecryptMessage(string message)
    {
        if (message is null)
            return Content($"null message");
        _aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        var messageBytes = HexToBytes(message);
        using (var target = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(target, _aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            var dbMessage = MemoryStreamToMessage(target);
            var jsonOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbMessage);
            return Content(jsonOut, "application/json");
        }
    }

    private static Message MemoryStreamToMessage(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        var text = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray()).TrimEnd();
        var jarray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text); //EXCEPTION HERE
        var list = jarray.ToObject<List<string>>();
        var storableMessage = new Message { Body = list[1], Email = list[0], Date = DateTime.Now };
        return storableMessage;
    }

    public static byte[] HexToBytes(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("Hex string must have even number of digits");
        byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
            arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
        return arr;
    }

    public static int GetHexVal(char hex)
    {
        int val = hex;
        return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 87);
    }
```

In `MemoryStreamToMessage`, `text` is having the symptom; so I get this kind of string:

> "�0�T.�z�\u000f��8��ߥcom\",\"My message is full\"]"

instead of:

> ["sender@server.com","My message is full"]

To me it looks like there is a shift in bytes, in the encoding, but I'm using a byte[]-UTF8 conversion on both side. Any thougths ?

Comment: You are using Encoding.Default in MemoryStreamToMessage, and that is not utf-8

Comment: Encoding.UTF8.GetString is giving the same problem.

Comment: Wrong characters are different each time, so I suspect a problem with the streams.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like you aren't setting the IV, since the error is in the first 16 bytes.